# How to find $\lim_{t_0 \to -\infty,\, t_1 \to \infty}\frac{\int_{t_0}^{t_1} (a + b \sin(2 \pi f t))^2 \,dt}{t_1-t_0}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

How do I find $$\lim_{t_0 \to -\infty,\, t_1 \to \infty}\frac{\int_{t_0}^{t_1} (a + b \sin(2 \pi f t))^2 \,dt}{t_1-t_0}?$$

Comment: Please see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask  and here:  https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question for how to ask a good question.

Comment: Expand parentheses. Use formula $\sin^2 x = \frac{1-\cos 2x}{2}$. Use the fact that $\langle \sin(kt+l) \rangle = 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let me evaluate the integral first
$$ \int_{t_0}^{t_1}(a+bsin(2\pi ft))^2 dt\\
 = \int_{t_0}^{t_1}(a^2+2absin(2\pi ft) + b^2sin^2(2\pi ft))dt \\
$$
[By using $sin^2x = \frac{1-cos2x}{2}$]
$$
 = \int_{t_0}^{t_1}(a^2+2absin(2\pi ft) + \frac{b^2}{2}-\frac{cos(4\pi ft)}{2})dt \\
=(a^2+\frac{b^2}{2})(t_1-t_0)-\frac{ab}{\pi f}cos(2\pi ft_1)+\frac{ab}{\pi f}cos(2\pi ft_0) - \frac{sin(4\pi ft_1)}{8\pi f} + \frac{sin(4\pi ft_0)}{8\pi f}
$$
Now we can go back to our limit
$$
\lim_{t_0 \to -\infty, t_1 \to \infty} \frac{(a^2+\frac{b^2}{2})(t_1-t_0)-\frac{ab}{\pi f}cos(2\pi ft_1)+\frac{ab}{\pi f}cos(2\pi ft_0) - \frac{sin(4\pi ft_1)}{8\pi f} + \frac{sin(4\pi ft_0)}{8\pi f}}{t_1-t_0}
$$
$$
\implies a^2 + \frac{b^2}{2} + \lim_{t_0 \to -\infty, t_1 \to \infty}\frac{-\frac{ab}{\pi f}cos(2\pi ft_1)+\frac{ab}{\pi f}cos(2\pi ft_0) - \frac{sin(4\pi ft_1)}{8\pi f} + \frac{sin(4\pi ft_0)}{8\pi f}}{t_1-t_0}
$$
The given limit tends to zero as the denominator grows to $\infty$ and the numerator oscillates between small finite values.

Thus the entire expression evaluates to

$$
a^2 + \frac{b^2}{2}
$$